# Spring + Hibernate4 Error CurrentSessionContext is always null

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

I'm using Hibernate 4 with spring 3.1 in a simple java Apllication.

I use the following code to create  the Spring SessionFactory and then convert it into a hibernate SessionFactory:
pls waht is missing here ... Is this the right way to go?? Or do I miss something..? pls help!

```
.....
......
context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"spring.xml"});
    return (SessionFactory) context.getBean("mySessionFactory");
......
```

The CurrentSessionContext ofthe sessionfactory is always null!
So I cant execute

```
sessionFactory.getcurrentSession()
```

-> gives me an java.lang.NullPointer Exception

myBean Declarations in spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">



 <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
  </bean>

      <bean id="mySessionFactory"  name="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="mappingResources">

          <list>
            <value>TblUrls.hbm.xml</value>
          </list>
        </property>
         <property name="hibernateProperties">
             <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext</prop>
              </props>
        </property>
      </bean>
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref local="mySessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "transactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "mySessionFactory" />

    </bean>
<!--   <bean id="myProductDao" class="hib.TblUrlsHome"> -->
<!--     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/> -->
<!--   </bean> -->

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do
`sessionFactory.openSession();`

This should solve your problem.